# I cannot select <title> tag in Atom XML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, title, atom-feed

I get Atom data through Ajax using jQuery.

I write

```
$(xhr).find('entry id').eq(0).html();
```

is OK.

But

```
$(xhr).find('entry title').eq(0).html();
```

can not select anything.

title tag is actually exist.

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

That is because there is no `title` element in the Atom XML. The actual name is `atom:title` if the XML namespace `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom` was mapped to the namespace prefix `atom`.

Your problem is that jQuery is a HTML library, not an XML library. Therefore, it has some shortcomings when it comes to handling real XML data.

What you need is a plugin. This [IBM developerworks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-feedjquery/) should give you some idea what I'm talking about and how to solve it.

Comment: +1 You're the only one that realizes the data is XML from an Ajax request and not HTML, as well as "jQuery is an HTML library, not an XML library"

Comment: What frustrating is that I know the problem now but I don't know the solution. My atom is a Google Picasa web albums' atom. It looks like this: http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#ListAlbums

Comment: @dfdb: Read the article. It contains the explanation and the solution.