# I cannot select <title> tag in Atom XML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, selector, title, atom-feed

I get a Google Picasa web albums' atom data through Ajax using jQuery. This atom data looks like this:

http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#ListAlbums

When I write

```
$(xhr).find('entry id').eq(0).html();
```

it is OK.

But

```
$(xhr).find('entry title').eq(0).html();
```

does not select

The `<title>` tag exists.

Please tell me how to resolve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: What does `alert($(xhr).find('entry title').length)` say?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957295/i-cannot-select-title-tag-in-atom-xml-using-jquery

Comment: I tryed this code and it alerts: 0

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery selector for all nodes in a given namespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580999/jquery-selector-for-all-nodes-in-a-given-namespace)