# jQuery selector for all nodes in a given namespace

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I can easily select all nodes with a given name in a namespace:

```
$("namespace\\:nodename")
```

But I need more: I want to select all nodes in a given namespace. Ideally, this:

```
$("namespace\\:*")
```

But the wildcard is not accepted.

TIA for your lights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the [all selector](http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/) is not supported with a namespace, you can use it on its own (to match all the elements), then apply [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to check the namespace yourself:

```
$("*").filter(function() {
    return this.nodeName.toLowerCase().indexOf("namespace:") == 0;
});
```