# Is there a way to unbind non-namespaced events only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Is there a way to unbind events that are not part of a specific namespace in jQuery? As inm is there a default namespace to which events belong to if they are not specified a namespace by the developer?

Ex:

```
$('#id').bind('click.myEvents', handler); //a click with a specific namespace: myEvents
$('#id').bind('click',handler2); //a click without a specific namespace
```

Would I be able to target the second click event without affecting the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
// unbinds non-namespaced event handlers
function unbind( elem, type ) {   
    $.each( $( elem ).data( 'events' )[ type ], function () {
        if ( this.namespace === '' ) {
            $( elem ).unbind( type, this.handler );
        }
    });
}
```

and then:

```
unbind( elem, 'click' );
```

where `elem` is  reference to your DOM element (`var elem = $( '#id' )[0];`).

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/2p25N/1/

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437958/jquery-exclude-this-from-selector/437979#437979) shows how to select elements that are not part of another selector. I think you might be able to do a select of everything not [in a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580999/jquery-selector-for-all-nodes-in-a-given-namespace/6581136#6581136).
I've never tried it though, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware of but you can attach all those other generic events to your own generic namespace. The relevant handlers don't overwrite each other's references.

If that's too much of a huge-app hassle to implement and you're worried about the cost of unbinding and then rebinding too many elements in the namespace, look into JQ's "delegate" method and event delegation in general if you're not familiar.

Events bubble up to parent elements. Event delegation uses this behavior to put one handler at a parent choke-point, check the event object to see what the original element the event was triggered from, and then execute the behavior. It's not a ton of overhead to bind/rebind on one element so that might be your best bet.